# How to move from beta to stable releases of OS X

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program

I have this VM which is currently on OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4 Beta

I would like stop downloading beta in future and just use latest stable version

I have [unenroll](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll) from the beta program

Now when 10.11.4 Stable version becomes available would i be able to upgrade to that one?

What is the best way to unenroll and go to stable releases in future?

Comment: I'd recommend [using `seedutil`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/439586/493304)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the link you posted:

> It is recommended that you keep your device enrolled in the program until the next commercial version of the software you are testing becomes available from the Mac App Store. If you must reinstall a previously-released version of OS X, you need to restore your Mac using the Time Machine backup that you created before you installed the OS X public beta.

So, you could [leave now](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211795/5472) and then when 10.11.4 is released to everyone, the App Store will update your beta with no need to erase or back up anything.

Answer (score 3):

Apple Store preferences options disappeared on newer releases and so far the only way to unenroll seems to be via the command line

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```

Comment: The `--clear-catalog` command is deprecated. Here is the error message I got when I ran this command on Catalina Beta: "Changing the Software Update catalog is deprecated. The ability to specify a custom catalog will be removed in a future release of macOS."