# Catalina keeps on downloading unwanted Monterey-Installer without any notification

Tags: catalina, upgrade, monterey

I am running Catalina 10.15.7 on an iMac 2020.
I have turned off the option "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" in the Preferences pane.
I do not want to upgrade to Monterey. I want to manage all updates myself.
However, four times until now the machine has downloaded the 12Gb "Install macOS Monterey.app" into /Applications without any notification. There was no indication this is happening. I just happened to find the "Monterey installer" in /Applications. Each time I have deleted the installer manually, but the OS keeps on downloading it again and again.
Does anyone know how to stop the OS downloading the unwanted "Install macOS Monterey.app" automatically without any notice?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in Advanced… because it's possible for the main box to be unchecked, but components inside to remain checked.
e.g.

[image]

[image]

It *should* show a partial indicator, but it doesn't always

[image]

Comment: Only "Check for updates" is turned ON. All other options are turned OFF.

Comment: OK - I'd try the 'switch it off then on again' approach. Enable everything individually, reboot, disable it all again, reboot. See if it sticks.

Comment: No success. Today the OS started to download the Monterey installer again.

Comment: Hmmm… not sure then. As far as I know that setting should be global, but is there another account on the Mac that could have set it differently? I'm out of ideas after that, sorry.

Comment: After turning off everything, even "Check for updates", a message appears saying: updates for this mac are managed externally. Any idea what exactly is behind this message and how to revers this?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/432585/85275 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/232188/85275 It's often as a result of beta participation.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not at all versed in remote management, but doesn't "managed externally" also suggest the possibility that the OP's Mac came from an organization (business or school) that centrally managed its students' or employees' computers, and that the business or school has never "released" the OP's computer?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - it could be, but beta participation sometimes throws up an odd one for this 'managed by swscan.apple.com'. OP never came back to confirm or deny this was the case...

Comment: Have same prob. No Download is checked and the ntb is not from corp/uni. It just keeps downloading 12.45 GB. Tried also leaving the name - just deleted the content.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and 2.10.2022 I did this and it still did not re-download 12GB.

### Steps taken:

###### Permissions/chmod was:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root wheel 96 Sep 25 21:31 Install macOS Monterey.app

$ stat -f %A Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app
755
```

###### Deleting 12GB file

```
/Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/SharedSupport]$ sudo rm SharedSupport.dmg

Password:
```

###### Creating fake file..

```
/Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/SharedSupport]$ sudo touch SharedSupport.dmg

[ad@mbp /Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/SharedSupport]$ ll

total 0

-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 0B Oct 2 17:53 SharedSupport.dmg
```

#### Nice and small..

```
$ du -sh Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/

22M Install macOS Monterey.app/
```

##### Locking it for anybody

```
/Applications]$ sudo chflags uchg,schg Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app
```

I **un**checked "Check for updates" then clicked <kbd>ok</kbd>. Checked it again just to be sure:

[image]

### 23 days later I still dont see 12GB file.. I won.

Comment: 1 December. Still winning. :)