# macOS updated to Beta despite opting out

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program

This morning I was surprised seeing that my Mac mini has updated to 10.12.2 (16C32e) beta although I did opt out under the System Preferences from receiving future beta updates [image: (Screenshot].

I am an Enterprise Developer so I believe that this is part of the Developers Beta and not the Public Beta, I mainly develop on iOS and would rather keep working on a non-beta machine so that my development could go smoothly without any beta bumps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yosemite - Pre-release: How do I opt out installing the beta seed?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154640/yosemite-pre-release-how-do-i-opt-out-installing-the-beta-seed)

Comment: @fsb I believe that the one you're referring is about the Public-Beta and my problem might have to do with part of my Developer account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following Terminal command to manually reset the Software Update catalog to the default end-user list:

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```

This won't remove the current beta build from your Mac, but it should reset to the correct release version next time one comes out.

Comment: Will try it I guess before the next Beta as I don't want to stay stuck with the first beta.
I'll update you then with my findings

Comment: Since Apple released 10.12.2 to the general public I now ran that command and received in response "Changed catalog to Apple production";
I'll now wait for the next Beta to pop-up on the Developers site and I hope that by then I shouldn't see these Betas popping into my updates.